# How to inflate different context menu from the same view dynamically

Tags: java, android

I have a Fragment with an EditText. The EditText displays a primary ContextMenu when it is long-pressed.
Now, I need to display a different ContextMenu when it is long-pressed and the application is in ActionMode.

With the code below, I can only display the same ContextMenu every time.
I think calling OnCreateContextMenu() when onCreateActionMode() and onDestroyActionMode() are called may be part of the solution, but I need parameters and I don't know how to properly write it.

```java
   EditText mEditText1;

   public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_client, container, false);
        mEditText1 = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_id);
        registerForContextMenu(mEditText1);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        if (mActionMode == null){
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.edittext_context_menu, menu);   
        } else {
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.another_edittext_context_menu, menu);   
        }
    }

    private ActionMode mActionMode;
    private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallBack = new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.client_action_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.cancel:
                    mode.finish();
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            mActionMode = null;
        }
    };
```

I expect the EditText to show 2 different ContextMenu, depending on if the application is in ActionMode or not.

Edit: edited the code with the solution

Answer (score 0):

On your "onCreateActionMode()" and "onDestroyActionMode()", call registerForContextMenu(your_edit_text). And check current mode to show suitable menu

Comment: Thank you, it worked. But actually, you don't need to call registerForContextMenu everytime, just once when you create the Activity/Fragment.
The only thing missing in my code was checking for the current mode on onCreateContextMenu